# Eclipse: Debug war in ear when the war-file only is a maven-dependency instead of an eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, war

We have the following packaging:

```
something.ear (eclipse-project)
+webstuff.war (maven dependency only)
+businessstuff.ejb (eclipse-project)
```

Packaging works perfectly and I am able to debug all the businessstuff. But how can I make the sourcecode of webstuff.war visible in eclipse and therefore set brakepoints and debug it?

Answer (score 0):

ear and war have only java class files(which is not editable) and not java source code. Better approach is to use some logging framework(i personally prefer log4j).

Every java project developed nowadays have used some logging framework, better search for them in the ear and war files.

On extracting the war file u can see some xml or .properties file which will say what loggong framework it uses.

Comment: Logging addresses another aspect. We'd like to gain access to the sourcecode within the IDE. Because we build the ear by maven (and m2eclipse) the IDE could download and provide readable access to the sourcefiles exactly the same way as it does when referencing an arbitrary jar file by maven. It shows you the source, let you set brakepoints as if the code was in your workspace.

Comment: if u hav the source code means create new project and import the source code to ur project.

Comment: Thats not an option because it is generated code that gets updated if interfaces change. And one is not allowed to perform changes to the generated code.